# icarousel not displaying items

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, icarousel

I've been working with iCarousel for about a week now, and I've had great success with outside testing. Now, I'm trying to put it into my app and it won't display the views. I was using UIViews to be displayed originally, which was working fine in my test programs, but due to sheer frustration im going as basic as possible and have literally just copied everythinng over from the examples. I connected the delegate and datasource, I called reloadData, ive done everything i could possibly find to fix this and it's not getting fixed. here's some code implementing the actual icarousel:

```
- (IBAction)coverflowPressed:(id)sender {
    self.carousel = [[iCarouselExampleViewController alloc]
    initWithNibName:@"iCarouselExampleViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:self.carousel animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The rest of the code is basically copied from an example that works outside my app. As i mentioned, i DID connect the delegate and dataSource. It displays the background just fine, but it's like the carousel is empty; it has no items in it, and yes, there ARE items in it. any ideas for me?

**EDIT**

Maybe i connected the delegate and datasource wrong. could somebody maybe explain how to do that from an app thats already halfway through production?

Breakpoints prove that it's never reaching carousel-specific functions, like viewForItemAtIndex or even awakeFromNib. viewDidLoad is called, so i set the delegate and datasource in there. Originally they were set in the nib but i changed it to programmatically. anyways heres my viewdidload method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.carousel.delegate = self;
self.carousel.dataSource = self;

//configure carousel
_carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;

}
```

it reaches the end of this function but it never goes any farther with it...